# Meteor/Mongo - Ensuring that one collection gets filled before another

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

Is there a way to ensure that one script runs before another in Meteor? I'm currently developing some software and using sample data for now. I'm a bit curious if there's a way that I can fill a particular collection only after another collection that it depends on has been filled

For example, An `Invoices` collection that has a `patient_id: Patients.findOne(...)` field that depends on the Patients collection actually having data. Is there a way to perform this other than having them on the same file, with `Patients` being filled before `Invoices`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to create test data in the right order, then you can run the test data generator for `Invoices` in a `Tracker.autorun`. This will be run reactively:

```
Meteor.startup(()=>{
  Tracker.autorun(()=>{
    if ( Patients.find().count() && !Invoices.find().count() ){
      populateInvoices();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Turns out Tracker.autorun() is [limited to the client](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun). I can't run it on the server

Comment: But with [this package](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-server-autorun) I can run the Tracker.autorun in the server :)